# How can I protect my .factory from minification?

Tags: angularjs

I have this function in AngularJS.  Can someone tell me how I can protect it so that it can be minified:

```
.factory('isEmailAvailable', function (appConstant, $q, $http) {
    return function (email) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var url = appConstant.baseUrl + '/api/user/existsByEmail';
        $http({
            url: url,
            method: "PUT",
            data: {
                email: email
            }
        }).then(function () {
                // Found the user, therefore not unique.
                deferred.reject("User name is taken");
            }, function () {
                // User not found, therefore unique!
                deferred.resolve();
            });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you mean is to protect dependency injection of this function:

```
function (appConstant, $q, $http) {}
```

To do that, change it to an array, telling Angular what you are injecting:

```
['appConstant', '$q', '$http', function (appConstant, $q, $http) {}]
```

so it would look like this

```
.factory('isEmailAvailable', ['appConstant', '$q', '$http', function (appConstant, $q, $http) {
  // Your code here
}])
```

If you are using [gulp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp) to automate building your app (it's totally worth it), you can use the [gulp-ng-annotate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ng-annotate) module to do this automatically without adding cruft to the original code.

Comment: I will mark as answered later. Unfortunately stackoverflow has a problem in my region and none of the images are appearing (any browser). I can't actually find the place where I need to click to accept :-(